# How to use uuid with postgresql gist in EXCLUDE constraint

Tags: postgresql, btree-gist

I'm getting error while I use Exclude constraint using gist

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_product ADD EXCLUDE USING gist (base_id WITH =, lifetime WITH &&);

ERROR:  data type uuid has no default operator class for access method "gist"
HINT:  You must specify an operator class for the index or define a default operator class for the data type.
```

Note:
`base_id` datatype is uuid, 
`lifetime` datatype is period

I am using PostgreSQL 9.4. I have to use 9.4 only as I don't have any other option since I am unable to install `temporal` extension in 9.5, 9.6 and 10 are gives an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need the [`btree_gist`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/btree-gist.html) extension for that:

> `btree_gist` provides GiST index operator classes that implement B-tree equivalent behavior for the data types `int2`, `int4`, `int8`, `float4`, `float8`, `numeric`, `timestamp with time zone`, `timestamp without time zone`, `time with time zone`, `time without time zone`, `date`, `interval`, `oid`, `money`, `char`, `varchar`, `text`, `bytea`, `bit`, `varbit`, `macaddr`, `macaddr8`, `inet`, `cidr`, **`uuid`**, and all `enum` types.

Unfortunately support for `uuid` was only added in v10.

With v10, you should be able to use

```
base_id gist_uuid_ops WITH =
```

in your exclusion constraint.

With 9.4, you could cast the column to a different type first:

```
(base_id::text) gist_text_ops WITH =
```

Comment: still getting error `ERROR:  operator class "gist_uuid_ops" does not exist for access method "gist"
STATEMENT:  ALTER TABLE tbl_product ADD EXCLUDE USING gist (base_id gist_uuid_ops WITH =, lifetime WITH &&);`

Comment: Maybe you installed the extension in a schema that is not in your `search_path`. What do you get for `\dx btree_gist` and `SELECT opcowner::regrole, opcnamespace::regnamespace FROM pg_opclass WHERE opcname = 'gist_uuid_ops';` ?

Comment: # \dx btree_gist 
                     List of installed extensions
┌────────────┬─────────┬────────┬─────────────────────────────────────┐
│    Name    │ Version │ Schema │             Description             │
├────────────┼─────────┼────────┼─────────────────────────────────────┤
│ btree_gist │ 1.0     │ public │ support for indexing common datatypes in GiST                          │
└────────────┴─────────┴────────┴─────────────────────────────────────┘
(1 row)

# SELECT * FROM pg_opclass WHERE opcname = 'gist_uuid_ops';
(0 rows)

Comment: Sorry, I missed that you are on 9.4. See my extended answer.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is correct, `btree_gist` is needed, however the suggested solution does not work (at least not in v12 in 2021). If you've been getting errors like in original question you should do the following:

```sql
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS btree_gist;
ALTER TABLE tbl_product ADD EXCLUDE USING gist (base_id WITH =, lifetime WITH &&);
```

As a bonus, I've been using it in Elixir & Ecto 3.5 and here's how to do this in Ecto migration:

```
execute "CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS btree_gist"
create constraint(:tbl_product, "constraint_name", exclude: ~s|gist ("base_id" WITH =, lifetime WITH &&)|)
```